# Run redis docker container from Dockerfile with authentication

Tags: docker, redis, dockerfile

I use official redis docker image. I need to have authentication with password
that's why I uncommented special block

```
# requirepass foobared
```

so, when I run command `docker run -v /myredis/conf/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf --name myredis redis redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf` redis asks me to provide password.

But I need to create docker image from Dockerfile. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM redis
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
CMD [ "redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf" ]
```

Redis doesn't ask me a password.
How to create Dockerfile, in order to have AUTH?

Answer (score 0):

Omit target file name in `COPY` command:

```
COPY redis.conf /usr/local/etc/redis/
```

Target is expected to be a path, not file name:

> The `dest` is an absolute path, or a path relative to WORKDIR, into
>   which the source will be copied inside the destination container.

As far as I undestood from you comments, you are trying to launch `redis` container instead of your own! This is a mistake, you need to use your one.

Lets say if you build it with command:

```
docker build -t my-redis .
```

Then you launch it with something like

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 -v /data:/data --name "redis-elk" my-redis redis-server --appendonly yes
```

Comment: And what about `CMD ["cat", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]` ?

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: And how do you launch container now? What is the command `docker ...`?

Comment: `docker run -d -p 6379:6379 -v /data:/data --name "redis-elk" redis redis-server --appendonly yes`

Comment: Ohh, sure! you are running **redis** container, and NOT your own. So everything, you have written in `Dockerfile` has no effect.

Comment: sorry, my fault, but when I user my own image, it doesn't take effect

Comment: You have to ensure file is correct. `cat` it in your image and see the console, or share it

Comment: `redis.conf` is in `/usr/local/etc/redis/`. Line with `requirepass foobared` is uncommented